# How to bind a property of a property in an ItemSource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, collectionview

I have a CollectionView with a DataTemplate, containing an Image, as the ItemTemplate.
In the ItemSource of the CollectionView I have objects which contain, among other things, one Image each. I want to bind the Source of this Image to the Source of the Image in my ItemTemplate.

I have tried these:

`<Image Source="{Binding iImage.Source}">`

`<Image Source="{Binding Source}" BindingContext="{Binding iImage}">`

`<Image Source="{Binding Path = iImage.Source}"">`

But none of them worked.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

XAML:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CV">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source=""/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Data Object:

```
public class Data
{
    //...
    public Image iImage;
    //...
}
```

Before displaying the CollectionView:

```
//...
List<Data> data = new List<Data>()
{
    new Data(image),
    //...
};
CV.ItemsSource = data;
//...
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without sufficient information, it will be near impossible to help you and your question likely will be closed until you provide enough context.

Comment: Image is a UI element.  It does not belong in a data class.  You should be storing the image url or file path or image data, not the Image control itself

Comment: also, you can only bind to **public properties**.  `public Image iImage;` is not a C# `property`